# Excel XML Line Breaks within Cell from PHP DOM

Tags: php, xml, excel, dom

I am trying to insert new lines into an Excel XML document. The entity that I need to insert is `&#10;` but whenever I insert that into PHP DOM, it just converts it to a normal line break.

This is what I am getting:

```
<Cell><Data>text
text2
</Data></Cell>
```

This is what I want:

```
<Cell><Data>text&#10;text2&#10;</Data></Cell>
```

I cannot figure out how to insert a new line and get it to encode that way, or add that character without it either double encoding it, or converting it to a new line.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a CDATA section...

Answer (score 5):

The correct format for this appears to be "&#10; ".  Note the trailing space.  It works in our applications when the trailing space is entered.

Answer (score 2):

When using CDATA and placing `&#10;` within the CDATA, Excel sees it as the actual text, not the character.  What I had to do is place the literal line break into the CDATA section and set the cell style to wrap. I added this to the default XML Style:

```
<Alignment ss:Vertical="Bottom" ss:WrapText="1"/>
```

That should do it for anyone looking to do this with PHP DOM, or any other XML creator.

Comment: ss:WrapText is the magic key.
CDATA or &#10; are not necessary.

Answer (score 1):

So, the wrap text option is needed, but for myself I couldn't get the correct result until I used the `&#13;` entity character, which is a carriage return `\r`.