# Rails 4, replacing "\n" with "&#10;" for use in XML spreadsheets in excel

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xml, excel, escaping, gsub

I'm writing an application that exports certain data into a specifically formatted Excel document.  I'm building an XML spreadsheet file using this document (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa140066(v=office.10).aspx#odc_xmlss_x:pagesetup)

and so far have it all working.  BUT to get it working I had to use ".html_safe" in several fields which is dangerous in this instance as some of the fields being exported contain user entered data.

Basically to get a new line inside an excel cell you use `"&#10;"` instead of the usual \n

I'm currently using this in my erb:

(edited 8/8/2014 for clarity)

```
<% @tickets.each do |t| %>
  <Row>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="borders"><Data ss:Type='String'>
      <%=t.business_impact.gsub("\n","&#10;").html_safe %>
    </Data></Cell>
  </Row>
<% end %>
```

but is there a better way to do this that wont "html_safe" the entire string?

Comment: Just as a quick extra note, I struggled with this for awhile and eventually realized I needed to use the &#13; entity character, which is a carriage return "\r" before it showed up correctly in excel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I strongly recommend you use ERB to generate XML formated Excel document.

First you should create an excel template. You can create an excel document with only 1 row 3 columns, and save it using xml format, then change the file name to xxx.erb.

Change the erb file with your model instance variables. I can give you my sample here:

```
 <Worksheet ss:Name="sheet1">
  <Table>
   <Column ss:Width="30" />
   <Column ss:Width="200" />
   <Column ss:Width="300" />
   <Column ss:Width="400" />
   <Row>
        <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">C1</Data></Cell>
        <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">C2</Data></Cell>
        <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">C3</Data></Cell>
   </Row>
   <% @yourmodels.each do |ds| %>
   <Row>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String"><![CDATA[<%safe_concat ds.c1 %>]]></Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String"><![CDATA[<%safe_concat ds.c2 %>]]></Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String"><![CDATA[<%safe_concat ds.c3 %>]]></Data></Cell>
   </Row>
   <% end %>
  </Table>
 </Worksheet>
```

**UPDATE:**
Reference to another question of [excel-xml-line-breaks-within-cell-from-php-dom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1027231/excel-xml-line-breaks-within-cell-from-php-dom), 
and article [safebuffers and rails 3.0](http://yehudakatz.com/2010/02/01/safebuffers-and-rails-3-0/).
Update code `<Cell><Data ss:Type="String"><%= ds.c1 %></Data></Cell>`
to `<Cell><Data ss:Type="String"><![CDATA[<%safe_concat ds.c1 %>]]></Data></Cell>` .

These codes are just part of my sample, just like other html templates. Don't worry about new line in data, don't need html_save, it works well.

And in your controller, you should add responed to xls or xml format.

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html # index.html.erb
  format.xls # index.xls.erb
  format.xml # index.xml.erb
end
```

Additionally if you want to create a file locally instead of return a file from browser. You can use ERB class method like below:

```
        @yourmodels = ...
        f = File.new( 'youmodels_out.xml', "w") 
        f_template = File.open( 'template_file_name.erb' )
        erb = ERB.new( f_template.read ) 
        f.print erb.result( binding )                
        f_template.close
        f.close
```

Comment: I am using erb the basic layout is this:
<% @tickets.each do |t| %>
  <Row>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="borders"><Data ss:Type='String'><%= t.business_impact.gsub("\n","&#10;").html_safe %></Data></Cell>
  </Row>
<% end %>

the problem is that without the gsub \n for the &#10; charachter, new lines entered by users are just showing as all being on one line in excel, and without html_safe the &#10; charachter is fully escaped and just comes out as those litteral characters.

Comment: Use a CDATA section to contain user entered data, instead of gsub and html_safe. I changed erb template in my answer and another question you can reference to.

Comment: This worked perfectly! thank you so much, my app is running a lot more safely now!