# How to preserve line breaks when exporting addresses from Ruby to Excel XML?

Tags: ruby, xml, excel

I am trying to generate an `.xls` file with my Ruby on Rails application.

Everything works great, except for the addresses which are displayed all in one line. I would like them to have line breaks to be more readable. (In the MySQL database they are saved with line break characters as well.)

I have tried all sorts of things, including this one...

```
# index.xsl.erb

<Cell><Data ss:Type="String"><%= invoice.address.gsub!("\n", '&#13;') %></Data></Cell>
```

... but to no avail. Excel simply converts my line break characters to `&amp;#13` making it look even more ugly.

Any ideas how to get around this?

Comment: [Have you seen this post?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25047405/rails-4-replacing-n-with-10-for-use-in-xml-spreadsheets-in-excel)

Comment: Try using \r\n (Windows line break) instead of \n (Unix line break).

Comment: Try to use `"\x0D\x0A"`

Comment: @BrunoFacca: That makes the address disappear completely.

Comment: @farhatmihalko: Doesn't work either.

Comment: @GaganGami: No, I hadn't. But it helped me solve the problem. Thanks.

Comment: How about inserting &CHAR(10) at the end of each record? If that doesn't work, I'm all out of ideas. Sorry...

Answer (score 0):

OK, this is how I got it working:

```
<Style ss:ID="s1">
   <Alignment ss:Horizontal="Left" ss:Vertical="Distributed"/>
</Style>

<Cell ss:StyleID="s1"><Data ss:Type="String"><%= invoice.address.gsub("\n", '&#13;').html_safe %></Data></Cell>
```